# Can we find the Joint Distribution of a random vector when we know the marginals of each random variable and the correlation matrix?

Tags: probability, correlation, marginal-distribution

I am a research scholar in electrical engineering (power systems). I am working on probabilistic approaches for power system analysis and I am relatively new to this area. I am able to understand how to find the marginals of the wind speeds ( wind speeds at different locations will form my random vector) and correlation matrix. I am reading literature on various probabilistic approches and am curious to know if I can form a joint distribution or joint density of the random vector with the information. Please let me know your opinion or even refer to something that i can refer. I appreciate your help.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't, except in special cases such as when the random variables are jointly Gaussian: in this case, the marginals and the pairwise correlation coefficients completely determine the distribution.

In general, the joint distribution of a random variables $X_1 \ldots X_n$ is determined by the marginal distributions $F_i(c) = \mathbb P(X_i \ge c)$ together with a function $\psi: [0,1]^n \to [0,1]$ called a *copula*. The copula function is given by $$\psi(c_1 \ldots c_n) = \mathbb P\left(F_1(X_1) \ge c_1, \ldots, F_n(X_n) \ge c_n\right).$$
You can read more about copulas and their uses in probability and statistics [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(probability_theory)). Regardless of what measure of correlation is used (e.g. linear correlation, rank-correlation), there are examples of different joint distributions with the same marginals and correlation.

The intuition is that the dependence structure of the variables is an infinite-dimensional object (a copula), and a one-dimensional measure of correlation will not adequately summarize it in all cases.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and reference! Do you think that is it somehow possible to do the analysis from copula theory just with the historical samples of each random variable?

Comment: In general if you have a sequence of sampled random vectors $(X_{11},\ldots ,X_{n1})  \ldots (X_{1n},\ldots ,X_{nn}) $ then you can estimate the copula.

One way to do this is the plug-in method: you first estimate the marginal distributions $F_1 \ldots F_n$ using the data you have, then you use these estimated functions to estimate the copula. Google searching "copula estimation" should give you some results. 

On the other hand, if you don't know which samples of $X_1$ go with which samples of $X_n$ then this is impossible. Of course, then you can't estimate correlation either.

Comment: Ya, I know the sample set for a particular random variable. Thank you for the help. Will start some reading in this direction.